# Error in Email Attachment from memory stream but only after first send

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do a loop to send an email with the same attachments to different email: with the first sending there are no problems, from the second the attachments are corrupt:

```
    public Dictionary<MemoryStream, string> GetDocumentsForEmail(int idCorso)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<MemoryStream, string>();

        var documents = (from d in db.Documents
                         where d.IDCorso == idCorso
                         select d).ToList();
        if (documents.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var doc in documents)
            {
                var file = new MyFileHelper().GetDownloadFile(idCorso, doc.IDFileType);
                if (file != null)
                {
                    dictionary.Add(file.Item1, file.Item2);
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In helper file I've this:

```
    public Tuple<MemoryStream, string> GetDownloadFile(int IDCorso, int fileType)
    {
        var document = (from d in db.Documents
                         where d.IDCorso == IDCorso && d.IDFileType == fileType
                         select d).FirstOrDefault();
        if (document != null)
        {
            string fileName = document.FileName.Trim() + document.FileExtension.Trim();
            byte[] fileBytes = document.FileContent;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            return Tuple.Create(ms, fileName);
         }
        return null;
    }
```

Here call sendmail with loop

```
    ...
    var listAttachment = new List<Dictionary<MemoryStream, string>>();
    listAttachment.Add(GetDocumentsForEmail(idCorso));
    foreach (var item in users)
    {
        listTo.Clear();
        var emailUser = GetEmailUser(item.ci.IDUser).ToString();
        listTo.Add(emailUser);
        mail.SendEmail(listTo, ..., listAttachment);
    }
```

In other helper file send email

```
public class MyMailHelper
{
    public void SendEmail(List<string> mailTOList..., List<Dictionary<MemoryStream, string>> mailAttachment = null)
    {
       ...
       SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
       MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(){...}
       ...
       if (mailAttachment != null)
       {
          foreach (var item in mailAttachment)
          {
             foreach (var key in item.Keys)
             {
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(key, item[key]));
             }
          }
        }
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Everything works fine, but only with the first sending the attachments are readable, after they are corrupt!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am suspecting the issue is because stream/s is/are not closed. Since you have functionality spread across functions, try wrapping the stuff in `SendEmail` into using block -  `using(MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(){...} ) {  /* other part of SendEmail functionality goes in here.*/}`. Wrapping MailMessage  in using block is also crucial otherwise, is you set the app to run continuously, you will run into TCP PORTs exhaustion situation.

Comment: What happens,  when you reset the streams position on every mail?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are converting dictionary of attachments to list?

Comment: "If the stream's CanSeek property is false, the attachment and the MailMessage that contains it are not reusable. You must supply a stream that can be searched to reuse an attachment." found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_String_).  MemoryStream.CanSeek is false if the [stream is closed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.canseek?view=netframework-4.8).  I would construct the memory stream from byte arrays within `SendEmail`.

Comment: Why do you think that the stream is closed?

Comment: agree with @Zer0. instead of adding memory stream to dictionary, just add byte array to dictionary and then convert to MemoryStream in SendEmail function while adding attachments.

Comment: I think the dictionary is unrelevant, because it not closes the stream.

Comment: In debug the var MemoryStream "key" in `mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(key, item[key]));` contains same value on every mail (lenght 66497).<br>This is the same value as the attachment that I receive in the first email, but in the following ones it is lower... this is the strange thing.

Comment: set MemoryStream.Position=0 after using stream object.

Comment: @user2005016 I asked before: What happens, when you reset the streams position on every mail? Please be communicative. If you don't read our comments and ideas, then it's hard to help.

Comment: sorry @Pethical, but I didn't know what to answer you... your question made me think

Comment: @sam "converting dictionary of attachments to list" is the consequence of the code that was there before... now I have corrected it!

Comment: @Zer0 CanSeek property is true

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy I added `item.Key.Position = 0;` before `mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(key, item[key]));`and it works!!! But I don't understand: why do i need to reset if i make a new call to SendEmail at every loop with new MemoryStream? Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've reached the end of your stream, you won't be able to read more data from it.
that's why you should set it to 0 after using it.

> ms.Position=0;

Comment: but I send a **new stream** with every loop to SendMail... why doesn't it always start from position = 0?